# Android : Replacing a fragment inside an Activity's onPause() method gives NullPointerException

Tags: android, android-activity, fragment

I am trying to learn fragments in android and trying to replace fragment with another one in the Activity's `onPause()` method when the activity pauses.

My code for onPause method is :-

```
public void onPause(){
    super.onPause();
    System.out.println("ActivityA-onPause()-1");
    ArticleListFragment temp=(ArticleListFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.article_list_fragment);
    System.out.println("ActivityA-onPause()-2");
    if(!temp.isAdded()){    //problem
        System.out.println("ActivityA-onPause()-3");
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.activity_a, articleReaderFragment, new String("readerFragment"));
        System.out.println("ActivityA-onPause()-4");
    }
    System.out.println("ActivityA-onPause()-5");
}
```

When i execute the app on device, onPause() executes but prints only till " Activity-onPause()-2 " but does not print " Activity-onPause()-3 ".

I get error log as :-

```
06-13 00:25:10.946: I/System.out(17974): ActivityA-onPause()-1
06-13 00:25:10.946: I/System.out(17974): ActivityA-onPause()-2
06-13 00:25:10.946: D/AndroidRuntime(17974): Shutting down VM
06-13 00:25:10.946: W/dalvikvm(17974): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb4e04908)
06-13 00:25:10.961: E/AndroidRuntime(17974): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-13 00:25:10.961: E/AndroidRuntime(17974): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to pause activity {com.pravesh.fragments/com.pravesh.fragments.ActivityA}: java.lang.NullPointerException
06-13 00:25:10.961: E/AndroidRuntime(17974):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performPauseActivity(ActivityThread.java:3016)
06-13 00:25:10.961: E/AndroidRuntime(17974):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performPauseActivity(ActivityThread.java:2971)
06-13 00:25:10.961: E/AndroidRuntime(17974):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handlePauseActivity(ActivityThread.java:2949)
06-13 00:25:10.961: E/AndroidRuntime(17974):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:141)
06-13 00:25:10.961: E/AndroidRuntime(17974):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1251)
06-13 00:25:10.961: E/AndroidRuntime(17974):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-13 00:25:10.961: E/AndroidRuntime(17974):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
06-13 00:25:10.961: E/AndroidRuntime(17974):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039)
06-13 00:25:10.961: E/AndroidRuntime(17974):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-13 00:25:10.961: E/AndroidRuntime(17974):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
06-13 00:25:10.961: E/AndroidRuntime(17974):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
06-13 00:25:10.961: E/AndroidRuntime(17974):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
06-13 00:25:10.961: E/AndroidRuntime(17974):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-13 00:25:10.961: E/AndroidRuntime(17974): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
06-13 00:25:10.961: E/AndroidRuntime(17974):    at com.pravesh.fragments.ActivityA.onPause(ActivityA.java:37)
06-13 00:25:10.961: E/AndroidRuntime(17974):    at android.app.Activity.performPause(Activity.java:5206)
06-13 00:25:10.961: E/AndroidRuntime(17974):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnPause(Instrumentation.java:1226)
06-13 00:25:10.961: E/AndroidRuntime(17974):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performPauseActivity(ActivityThread.java:3002)
06-13 00:25:10.961: E/AndroidRuntime(17974):    ... 12 more
```

All I can understand is that it gives a null pointer exception but I don't know why.

Comment: probably you should check if temp is null

Comment: Or `fragmentTransaction` could be null. Find line 37 of `ActivityA.java`, as your `null` object is there.

Comment: Yeah I am also thinking that may be temp is null.
I inserted `Object obj=temp;
  if(obj.equals(null)){
   System.out.println("null temp");
  }` after temp declaration but it also doesn't printed "null temp".

Comment: if temp is null then calling equals will also lead to NPE.

Answer (score 0):

Try to call `super.onPause` after replacing your fragment and doing all other stuff.

Comment: Tried super.onPause() at the end of onPause() but same error, nothing different.

Comment: As long as I think I get the error in " if(!temp.isAdded()) " as I am not able to print "ActivityA-onPause()-3".

Comment: Fragment id is correct as if I remove code from the inside of onPause() it runs fine.

Comment: It looks like your tem var is null. You get nothing from FragmentManager this is possible only if the id is incorrect or there was no fragment with such id added at all.

Comment: Yeah you were pretty right. I used findViewByTag() instead of findViewById() for declaration of temp, and it worked fine.
Don't know why it gave error with findViewById() as I can see the the same ID provided in the gen->R->id .